# round command is unable to get required result

Tags: python

In the following code when I print h value in for loop it prints values of 1.2, 1.4, 1.6 . But I want exactly 1.20, 1.40, 1.60 . I tried to use round function but still result is same. How can I get exact values 1.20, 1.40, 1.60 inside the for loop?

```
low =[1.20, 1.40, 1.60, 1.80, 2.00, 2.20, 2.40]
for k in range(len(low)):
    h = round(low[k],2)
    print(h)
```

Comment: Look into *formatting* (something which you do on strings to cause them to display a certain way) rather than *rounding* (which is a mathematical operation not relevant for your concerns here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(h))
```

It isn't a rounding issue, but an output formatting issue. In other words, the number is correctly rounded, it's just that when printing the trailing zero isn't printed out, so you would want some formatting to force the zeros to be printed out.

Comment: I applied string formatting operator now the print function produces the exact result. But I also want that h value should be exactly 1.20,1.40. Because I have saved some files with these values when I try to load them it says that no such file or directory exists. and its reason is that h value is 1.2 and 1.4 instead of 1.20 and 1.40

Comment: @herry The numbers are stored as numbers in the computer. 1.2 doesn't differentiate from 1.20 in this case. It's only a matter of how it's presented to you, not how it's represented inside. You don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @herry The value 1.2 *is* the value 1.20. If you want to write `1.20` rather than `1.2` to a text file -- use string formatting in your write operations. This answer applies whether you print the string to the REPL or write it to a file.